# jQuery console.log while on submit in Firefox 54 does not work

Tags: jquery, firefox, console.log

i've got the following jQuery code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.serializejson.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
        
        
        <script>
        $(function(){
            console.log("fuuuuu");  // OK
            $('#foo').on("submit", function(){
              console.log("bar"); // not OK 
              alert("foo_bar");   // OK
            });
        });                  
 </script>
    </head>
<body>
        <form id="foo">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
        12
        3
        5</textarea>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why `console.log();` inside the `.on("submit")` function doesn't work in firefox? With chrome it all works fine, only firefox is going crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it work but after you click submit button it will reload the page so the log will be lost, use `.preventDefault()` to cancel action for submit button and see your log

```
$(function() {
  console.log("fuuuuu"); // OK
  $('#foo').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // will not reload page (post data)
    console.log("bar"); // OK 
    alert("foo_bar"); // OK
  });
});
```